# What is maximum number of ArcGIS Online Layers that can be added to ArcGIS Desktop (ArcMap)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layers, arcgis-online, limitations

I have added 6 ArcGIS Online layers to an ArcMap 10.3.1 project (.mxd). When I attempt to add additional online layers: "File --> Add Data --> Add Data from ArcGIS Online" ArcMap hangs for a second, releases, and no layer is added to the Table of Contents.

I have attempted clearing the Display Cache, as well as signing out of my AGOL Account. I am using an AGOL account affiliated with a University that does not have any credit limits. I have conducted a search and not been able to find any documentation from ESRI relating to maximum number of AGOL layers in an ArcMap project.

Has anyone else encountered this behavior, or detected a maximum number of AGOL layers?

Comment: @Jon and NULL.Dude you are both on to something. My data frame was set to a local coordinate system, as the first layer I added to my project was a county boundary. AGOL layers are initially capable of projecting on the fly, but as the number of layers increases, I begin to experience a decrease in performance. USA Historical Topo Maps 1:250,000 scale would not draw. Changing the data frame to EPSG 3857 WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere gets it to draw.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments, it appears that your problem is that your map dataframe is set to a different CRS than the online maps (which are all apparently EPSG 3867). Because of this, ArcGIS Online is trying to reproject the Online Layers on the fly, which is a huge draw on system resources.

You can fix this by simply changing your dataframe to display the same CRS as the Online Layers.